# Kubernetes PullImageError using Docker Hub with a private image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I'm struggling to get Kubernetes to work with my private hub.docker.com registry image.

I am using kubectl version: `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1+", GitVersion:"v1.1.0-alpha.0.1588+e44c8e6661c931", GitCommit:"e44c8e6661c931f7fd434911b0d3bca140e1df3a", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}`

and Vagrant `1.7.4` on Mac OS X `Yosemite 10.10.5`

I followed the instructions given here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/images.md#pre-pulling-images

In a nutshell, it says you should login to the registry then base64 encode the contents of the resulting `.docker/config.json`, and use that in a yaml document as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregistrykey
data:
  .dockercfg: eyAiYXV0aHMiOiB7ICJodHRwczovL2luZGV4LmRvY2tlci5pby92MS8iOiB7ICJhdXRoIjogImFXNTBjbWx1YzJsak9tSTJVVTR5Z...h1YkBpbnRyaW5zaWMud29ybGQiIH0gfSB9Cg==
type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg
```

Then feed that to kubectl. I then used the resulting key (here called `myregistrykey`) in my pod definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: authorities-backend
spec:
  containers:
    - name: authorities-backend
      image: intrinsic/authorities-backend:latest
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey
```

and `kubectl create`d it.

However, kubectl keeps failing to retrieve the image:

```
[root@kubernetes-master intrinsic]# kubectl get pods
NAME                  READY     STATUS           RESTARTS   AGE
authorities-backend   0/1       PullImageError   0          7m
```

docker pull on the Kubernetes master worked however.

What am I missing?

## UPDATE

**In the pod definition above, I had omitted to specify the registry host, i.e. docker.io. Fixing it, it becomes:
`image: docker.io/intrinsic/authorities-backend:latest`
However, the problem persists. Doing `kubectl get events -w` gets me:

`6s          0s         2         authorities-backend   Pod       spec.containers{authorities-backend}   Failed    {kubelet 10.245.1.3}   Failed to pull image "docker.io/intrinsic/authorities-backend": image pull failed for docker.io/intrinsic/authorities-backend, this may be because there are no credentials on this request.  details: (Error: image intrinsic/authorities-backend:latest not found)`

I know the secret has been properly registered, as I have it under `kubectl get secrets`:

`NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
default-token-a7s5n   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   2         51m
myregistrykey         kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         50m`**

Still confused...

Candide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is out of date, in that it refers to `.dockercfg` instead of `.docker/config.json`.  I will update it.

When you use the new `.docker/config.json` format, you need to set `type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` instead of `type: kubernetes.io/.dockercfg`.

Support for `type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` was added in v1.1.0 so it is supported by your server, but is not supported by your client (which is v1.1.0-alpha which predates v1.1.0).

When you use `type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`, it should validate your secret contents.

With `type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`, you do want to keep the `auths` wrapper.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18777 fixes the documentation.  Your review would be welcome.

Comment: Actually, due to an oversight, Kubernetes is not currently validating `type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`.  I wrote https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18790 to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for this Eric - the documentation works great. Minor complaint: I can't actually execute `nodes=$(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range.items[*].metadata}{.name} {end}')` (getting `error: output format "jsonpath={range.items[*].metadata}{.name} {end}" not recognized`) likely due to my ignorance on how to do this. Still would be nice if it was a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 5):

So, I kept researching the web for an answer to my problem and eventually found this:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7954#issuecomment-115241561

At the very end of the thread, jjw27 has nailed it. The [kubernetes documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/images.md#pre-pulling-images) mentions the `.dockercfg.json` file just to say that its contents needs to be base64-encoded. There are actually two issues with this file:

1. it looks like it morphed into another file actually, i.e. `.docker/config.json`
2. the auth info in this file is wrapped by an additional `auths` objects, which you have to get rid of.

Quoting jjw27

Did not work:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "hub.example.com:1024": {
      "auth": "asdf=",
      "email": "example@example.com"
     }
  }
}
```

Worked:

```
{
  "hub.example.com:1024": {
    "auth": "asdf=",
    "email": "example@example.com"
  }
}
```

Google, please update this doc!!

Message to Kubernetes devs #2: Also, not complaining with a malformed base64-encoded secret is very misleading. Please validate user input and complain if it contains errors.